# SQL Query to find common attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have SQL table with 3 Columns generated by ERP.

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| ProductID | Attribute |   Value    |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|       100 | Size      | Big        |
|       100 | Color     | Red        |
|       100 | Weight    | Heavy      |
|       200 | Size      | Small      |
|       200 | Color     | Red        |
|       200 | Weight    | Light      |
|       300 | Size      | Big        |
|       300 | Color     | Green      |
|       300 | Weight    | Heavy      |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

I want to query table to find Products with matching attributes. For example

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Attribute ='Size' AND Value = 'Big' AND Attribute ='Weight' AND Value = 'Heavy'
```

So returning products 100 and 300.

Comment: You have not explained what "find Products with matching attributes" means: What is the input? Just that table, or also some other(s), or also some parameter(s)/constant(s)? Why give a query when you are asking for a query? What is the desired query supposed to look like? What is the output supposed to look like in terms of the input? Please give example input & output. PS Why two different DBMS tags?

Comment: MySQL and/or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use a traditional "pivot query" and treat that as a "derived table", then you will get Size/Weight/Color as rows making it simple to filter.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4e062/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ERPout
    (`ProductID` int, `Attribute` varchar(6), `Value` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO ERPout
    (`ProductID`, `Attribute`, `Value`)
VALUES
    (100, 'Size', 'Big'),
    (100, 'Color', 'Red'),
    (100, 'Weight', 'Heavy'),
    (200, 'Size', 'Small'),
    (200, 'Color', 'Red'),
    (200, 'Weight', 'Light'),
    (300, 'Size', 'Big'),
    (300, 'Color', 'Green'),
    (300, 'Weight', 'Heavy')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      ProductID
    , Size
    , Color
    , Weight
FROM (
      SELECT
            ProductID
          , MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'Size' THEN VALUE END) AS Size
          , MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'Color' THEN VALUE END) AS Color
          , MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'Weight' THEN VALUE END) AS Weight
      FROM ERPout
      GROUP BY
            ProductID
      ) p
WHERE Size = 'Big'
      AND Weight = 'Heavy'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4e062/2/0)**:

```
| ProductID | Size | Color | Weight |
|-----------|------|-------|--------|
|       100 |  Big |   Red |  Heavy |
|       300 |  Big | Green |  Heavy |
```

Comment: Dude that works even better. Thanks a lot buddy. You are a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a conditional `SUM`:

```
SELECT ProductID
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ProductID
HAVING
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN Attribute = 'Size' AND Value = 'BIG' THEN 1
            WHEN Attribute = 'Weight' AND Value = 'Heavy' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) = 2
```

You can use `>= 2` if you want `ProductID`s with other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different ways to do this.  Here's one using conditional aggregation:

```
select productid
from yourtable
group by productid
having max(case when attribute = 'Size' then value end) = 'Big'
   and max(case when attribute = 'Weight' then value end) = 'Heavy'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6f79/1)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want pairs of products. Also I'm not hard-coding the values anywhere. If you need to change the set of attributes just modify the `having` clause.

```
select t1.ProductID, t2.ProductID
from
    T t1 inner join T t2
        on      t2.ProductID > t1.ProductID
            and t2.Attribute = t1.Attribute and t2.Value = t1.Value
group by
    t1.ProductID, t2.ProductID
having
        count(case when t1.Attribute = 'Size' then 1 end) = 1
    and count(case when t1.Attribute = 'Weight' then 1 end) = 1
```

I'm kind of leaning back toward thinking that an answer like Felix's is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the *ProductID*, this would be a short and efficient sollution:

```sql
SELECT ProductID
FROM product_info
WHERE Attribute ='Size'   AND Value = 'Big'
  OR  Attribute ='Weight' AND Value = 'Heavy'
GROUP BY ProductID
HAVING COUNT(ProductID) = 2
```

If you need all attributes in one row and you have defined a (unique/primary) key on (*ProductID, Attribute*) you might want to use a query like this:

```sql
SELECT size.ProductID, size.Value Size, color.Value Color, weight.Value Weight
FROM product_info size
JOIN product_info weight USING(ProductID)
LEFT JOIN product_info color
  ON  color.ProductID = size.ProductID
  AND color.Attribute = 'Color'
WHERE size.Attribute   = 'Size'   AND size.Value   = 'Big'
  AND weight.Attribute = 'Weight' AND weight.Value = 'Heavy'
```

The performance will be even better if you additionally define an index on *Value*.

Both queries are using the WHERE clause avoiding a full table/index scan. Depending on table size and data this can be a huge advantage, because of the early filtering.